# Is there any virtual machine which works on a PPC Mac running 10.4?

Tags: virtualization, powerpc

Is there any virtual machine which works on a PPC (non-Intel) Mac 10.4? I am killing myself finding a virtual machine for Mac 10.4. Everything that I found needs an Intel Mac.

Comment: Strictly speaking, "virtualization" is where both the host and guest see the same processor architecture (i.e. x86 in Intel Macs with Windows VMs). "Emulation" is where the host and guest see different architectures (i.e. PowerPC Mac OS running Windows on x86), and is what you want to do. While they're close enough that everybody will know what you're talking about, the distinction may help your search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary solution for PowerPC Macs was Microsoft's now-defunct [Virtual PC](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/6078/virtual-pc).  It was discontinued several years ago, so you'll really have to do some digging to find a copy.  (Be warned -- it runs slow as molasses.  You'd probably be better off buying a cheap PC.)

There's also [Q emulator](http://www.kju-app.org/), which supposedly runs on PowerPC, but I have never tried it.

Comment: Thanks Austin for you help. I am ok with the slow version because I do need it for an experiment. But unfortunately the only thing about Virtual PC that I have found so far is the updater which is the same as the link in your comment but I have failed to find the main program to install. Do you know where I can find it?

I will also be going to test the Q emulator. Thanks.

Comment: @Reza Q is quite good, but doesn't have all the features of the "mainstream" emulation platforms.

Comment: @Reza There are many people selling it on eBay -- try searching `Virtual PC Mac`, and be sure to get a recent version (v6 or v7).  Looks like most copies have sold for $10-40 recently.

Answer (score 2):

There is a download link for Virtual PC 7 on [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FdPua-wb0wo) that you may try.

If you're really desperate, the [Darwine](http://darwine.sourceforge.net/download.php) project released a few experimental builds of Wine that worked on PPC several years ago, but the project was dropped due to very poor performance, and I expect that you need to do a lot of hacking to get a program up-and-running…

Answer (score 0):

https://www.qemu.org/
has worked for this
man. here is a video
https://youtu.be/B-qhSxI0NtE

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different and taking the time to post an answer!  It's helpful to *expand* on your answer to further explain/clarify what you are attempting to communicate.

Answer (score -2):

Om my PPC PowerMac G3 I did have one installed the copy from my friend however the machine had a kernel issue due to trying to install a modified OS X Leopard and I had to restore the disk. Although I cannot remember the name I can assure you there is one and this one worked with XP which surprised me considering that XP is Intel and above XXDD.